# Chrome browser opens but doesn't want to go to a url

Tags: python

This is my code and for some reason when the browser opens it doesn't go to gmail.com. Any idea how to fix this?

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe")
time.sleep(5)
driver.get('gmail.com')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`driver.get()` requires valid (and a fully qualified) URL that starts with `"http"/"https"`. However, `driver.get("http://www.gmail.com")` will navigate to `"https://www.gmail.com"` but the `driver.get(gmail.com)` will simply get lost.

For the parsing you can use `startsWith` method:

```
if url.startswith("https"):
    # url is https
else:
    # url is http
```

If the url contains neither you can concat the url with `https://` or `http://` before sending the request.

**Note:**
I cannot cite a source for my claim but here's an explanation why might I say that:

> `driver.get()` requires valid URL that starts with `"http"/"https"`

While the official documentation for Selenium WebDriver may not explicitly state this requirement because it is a common assumption in web automation that you provide a complete and valid URL.

Comment: "*```driver.get()``` requires valid URL that starts with ```"http"/"https"```*" Can you cite a source for this claim? I can't seem to find anything regarding this requirement in the official docs.